# problems with hamcrest matcher and argThat method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, hamcrest

I got this piece of code in my testclass:

```
then(collector()).should().emit(eq(myStream), eq(myTuple),
        argThat(allOf(hasItem(anyString()), hasItem("test1"), hasItem("test2"))));
```

The problem is that I dont know the value of the first `Item`. I am only know that the value is of type `String`.

If I execute the test I got the message:

> Invalid use of argument matchers! 3 matchers expected, 5 recorded

Furthermore:

> This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
>       //incorrect:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String"); When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers. For example:
>       //correct:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

I cant see the problem right know.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks like your `anyString` comes from Mockito not Hamcrest...

Comment: Could you add your imports?

Comment: Hi Boris. you are right. it works with any(String.class). give it as answer and I will accept it. thx for the help

Comment: @StefanBeike I still second Manu in saying you should post your imports. Boris is right that `emit` should have a Mockito matcher for each parameter, and that `allOf` should only contain Hamcrest Matchers, but if `anyString` is the fourth matcher I don't see where the fifth recorded matcher comes in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cannot use Mockito Matchers when nesting matchers. You **must** use Hamcrest or other custom matchers instead. The underlying issue is that the argThat is counted as a mockito matcher as well as the anyString() and these matchers are being applied to a single argument causing the error (I have no idea why mockito doesn't support this). Changing over to a Hamcrest matcher for the anyString should resolve the issue. Try the following:

```
then(collector()).should().emit(eq(myStream), eq(myTuple),
    argThat(allOf(hasItem(isA(String.class)), hasItem("test1"), hasItem("test2"))));
```